# How do I get a hidden value from a <td> with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can't find the answer anywhere. I don't know how to get a hidden value from a `<td>` on jquery.

```
<td class='equis' value='8'>X</td>
```

I also tried putting the `value='8'` on a `<span>`, a `<p>` amongst others.

```
$('.equis').click(function(){
   var compra_id = $(this).val();
   alert("ID: "+compra_id);
});
```

But `compra_id` doesn't get the "8" value.

I've tried to solve it in a couple of other different ways but seems to me that the way to go should be something similar to this. What I want to do is actually very simple; hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Use a hidden input field, `<input type="hidden">` for that, not a `<td>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value` can only be retrieved using `val()` on form controls.

Suggest using a `data-` attribute instead since `value` is meaningless

```
<td class='equis' data-value='8'>X</td>
```

Then use

```
$('.equis').click(function(){
   var compra_id = $(this).data('value'); 
   alert("ID: "+compra_id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't use val() for table data.  try this instead:

```
$('.equis').click(function(){
    var compra_id = $(this).attr('value');
    alert("ID: "+compra_id);
});
```

Comment: they already set a `value` attribute: `<td class='equis' value='8'>X</td>`

Comment: you're right, my answer was unclear.  i edited it for clarity.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `attr` like following.

```
$('.equis').click(function(){
   var compra_id = $(this).attr('value'); 
   alert("ID: "+compra_id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO better if you could use **[data](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** attributes since value in `<td>` tag is not valide :

```
<td class='equis' data-value='8'>X</td>
```

In your js you could get the value like :

```
$('.equis').click(function(){
    var compra_id = $(this).data('value');
    alert("ID: "+compra_id);
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('.equis').click(function(){
  var compra_id = $(this).data('value');
  alert("ID: "+compra_id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
     <td class='equis' data-value='8'>X</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```